# For laying out Japanese text in a piece of graphic design do you need to stick to some rules?

Tags: grammar

Example I have the english text "enjoy music" which from google translate looks like this 
 音楽を楽しむ where music is 音楽 , so can I do this

を楽しむ -(enjoy)
                                                                                                音楽  -(music)

flush left

Comment: What do you mean by "flush left"?  I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @istrasci, I could be wrong, but I interpreted that to mean text aligned on the left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your text will be laid out basically as shown in your post, you have the grammar backwards -- English and Japanese put things in almost exactly the opposite order, broadly speaking.  So do this instead:

音楽を
楽しむ

This works better both grammatically and graphically: Japanese text design has a general bias towards things fitting neatly into boxes.  :)

If you can do a vertical layout, do this:

```
楽音  
し楽  
むを
```

Note that you shouldn't rotate the characters, and that the first character is at the top right.  Vertical Japanese (and Chinese) is read top-to-bottom, then right-to-left.  Imagine if you just took an English book and turned it 90° clockwise, but somehow each individual letter remained un-turned.

Meaning-wise, I'm not sure this says what you intend.  The Japanese is just a generic statement, *"`[someone: I, you, they, she]` enjoy(s) music".*  Is the English intended as a command or request?  If so, you'll have to change the Japanese.  One possibility:

音楽を
楽しんで

or:

```
楽音  
し楽  
んを  
で
```

Comment: Wow thanks! The intended meaning is "Come enjoy the music" ... I reduced it to "enjoy music " as I thought thats what a translation would reduce it self to in english.

Comment: I can do the very first one or second both will work. thanks!